# CSGO Market API 400 Bad Request

Tags: python, request, http-status-code-400

I recently started to code a bot to gather some info about CSGO skins and I came up with this request, which get an error code.

```
steam_login = {'Cookie': 'steamMachineAuth76561199034404601=[AUTH];steamRememberLogin=[TOKEN];steamLoginSecure=[TOKEN];',
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://steamcommunity.com", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"}
```

```
def item_buy_request(item_id):
    l = []
    r = req.get(f'https://steamcommunity.com/market/itemordershistogram?country=FR&language=ENGLISH&currency=3&item_nameid={item_id}&two_factor=0&norender=1', headers=steam_login)
    return r.text
```

Whenever I run my code I get empty brackets "[ ]", which means I get a 400 bad request error. I have done my research, and I draw 3 conclusion out of it.

1 - I tried to do the request by browsing the link, and it worked. So the issue do not come from the ***item_id*** string.

2 - I tried to do it in private navigation mode, and it worked. So the issue do not come from expired cookies (***steamsecurelogin***, etc...)

3 - I tried to run the request outside python with https://reqbin.com/. The strangest thing is that I copied every headers, which allowed me to successfully run the request in my browser and even with that, it did not work.

If you have any clue on how to successfully run the request in python, I'll take it. Ty !

Comment: My guess would be that there is something wrong in your url string

Comment: well... in fact there is a space in the item_id string... ty ^^